# Login form wont align

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I created a login form but it wont align to middle..

```
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="loginEmail">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="loginPassword">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

tell me if you need anything else

i tried adding this in my code

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set display properties to container.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).